# Fill it out later

Tags: phrase-meaning

CJ
Hey, that's my paper man. That's money.

TENPENNY
This is drug money.

CJ
My money, man...

PULASKI
Hey don't worry about it, I'll fill it out later.

from GTA:San Andreas (Video game)

Please explain what he means by saying: "Hey don't worry about it, I'll fill it out later" And why he says:”My money ,man...”?

Comment: Duplicate of a closed question on ELU. We usually 'fill out' a form, not money.

Comment: Is  this means he will give his money back later?

Comment: [Does this mean x, not is this mean...]

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently](https://www.grandtheftwiki.com/First_Mission_(GTA_SA)/Script) Puluski (a corrupt police officer) is speaking to Hernandez (a rookie police officer)  and means "I'll fill out the forms that police officers have to fill out fraudulently so we can steal some of this money and we won't be caught" or perhaps "I'll confisicate this money and do all the paperwork. I won't tell you that actually I'm planning to steal it."

There's not way to tell that from the words, you have to read the context.